# head problem: just two non adjacent columns please

Tags: r

So I was trying to look at a few columns and did head(mydf[76:82], n=20), which got me columns 76:82, for 20 rows. Excellent. Just what I wanted.

Next, however, I want to get just columns 76 & 82. I tried the following:

```
head(tu_timeadd[76&82]) #which just gave me the whole dataframe
head(tu_timeadd[76,82]) #which I'm pretty sure gave me the value for column 76, row 82?
head(tu_timeadd[76 |82]) #which gave me the whole thing again
```

anyway to just spit out the first few rows of columns 76 & 82 without having to subset it out?

Comment: `head(tu_timeadd[c(76,82)])`

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: FYI, `[76&82]` fails because in R, `x&y` is a logical operation, and anything non-zero is `TRUE`, meaning this is interpreted as `[TRUE&TRUE]` --> `[TRUE]` --> all data; `[76|82]` is very much the same issue. `[76,82]` is *row* 76, *column* 82, I suggest you read more on [`?[`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).